# An Error when installing pgadmin 4 in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pip, pgadmin-4

i start installing pgadmin 4 in my ubuntu 20.4 machine but i found this problem. When i install pgadmin 4 throught pip3 install pgadmin4 i found these problem. Anyone can help me to solve the problem please ?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /root/pgadmin4/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n3i52upe/gssapi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n3i52upe/gssapi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-n3i52upe/gssapi/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-n3i52upe/gssapi/
Complete output (13 lines):
/bin/sh: 1: krb5-config: not found
In distributed package, building from C files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-n3i52upe/gssapi/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
    link_args = shlex.split(get_output(f"{kc} --libs gssapi"))
  File "/tmp/pip-install-n3i52upe/gssapi/setup.py", line 34, in get_output
    res = subprocess.check_output(*args, shell=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'krb5-config --libs gssapi' returned non-zero exit status 127.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Install `krb5-devel`?

Comment: No, i did not install kerberos yet

Answer (score 3):

Just got the error, after a little search found out that the problem comes from a dependency to a package of implementation of Kerberos:
So by installing this package the problem will be solved:

```
sudo apt install libkrb5-dev
```

https://github.com/pythongssapi/requests-gssapi/issues/14